Logical replication delay in postgres16(Bidirectional)
We have noticed logical replication delay at times(even non peak hours also) in postgres16 bidirectional replication.
Even though we configured bi directional, traffic is from prod1 to prod2 only.
During delay (150GB) no extra traffic,no n/w issue.no IO issue and no tx running more than 1 sec(This is oltp app all tx are in milliseconds).
Noticed from pg_stat_replication_slots total_tx rate is going near zero as shown in graph.not able to understand Why logical decoding going to zero?
grafana logical replication Lag
Only observed **aggressive vacuum **during lag time apart from nothing observed.
And the wait event Walsenderwritedata is noticed from pg_stat_activity
Want to know ,Why logical decoding went low?
During the issue noticed fallowing log from Subscription end:
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 27.69    0.168862           5     29348           epoll_wait
 25.18    0.153546           2     73853     73521 recvfrom
 19.43    0.118466           2     44281     29343 sendto
 16.32    0.099533           3     29238           read
 10.11    0.061676           5     12255           pread64
  1.27    0.007728           1      4827           rt_sigprocmask
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.609811           3    193802    102864 total
sendto: resource unavailable errors


Perhaps the answer can be found in the Postgres log file; did you have a chance to look there?

I verified, nothing much ,noticed from OS level few issues, updated the same above. Thanks

The documentation describes WalSenderWriteData as

Waiting for any activity when processing replies from WAL receiver in WAL sender process.

So perhaps there are network problems, or replay on the subscriber is delayed by a lock or something else.  See what the apply workers on the subscriber are doing.
The many errors in the sendto and recvfrom system calls indicate a network problem. So you should fix your network, then your problem will probably be solved.

Thanks for the response @Laurenz,I have edited the response and copied the Subscription behavior during the time.

You should edit the question and add information there, preferably not as an image. Some more clarity would also be useful. For example, is the aggressive autovacuum on the publisher or the subscriber? Does the problem only happen during aggressive autovacuum?

It happens at times(bi weekly once or twice),no service running &no long running tx more than 1 sec.

And noticed last_end_time in subscription is very slowly moving(If we know why this is happening ,we got the issue)

typo ,it's latest_end_time from pg_stat_statements is not upto date ,rest all are with almost with current time. select received_lsn,last_msg_send_time,last_msg_receipt_time,latest_end_lsn,latest_end_time from pg_catalog.pg_stat_subscription;
